# os.system does not allow a command with >

Tags: python

I can use the following command in linux.

```
ls > >(tee -a a)
```

But python os.system does not allow the syntax.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("ls > >(tee -a a)") sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `>' sh: -c: line 0: `ls > >(tee -a)' 256
>>>
```

Do we need any special ways to escape any chars?

Comment: `sh` doesn't allow that syntax. POSIX shell is not bash; `os.system()` uses `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash` so behaviour differs.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to accomplish, you likely should just use Python.

Answer (score 2):

As alluded to in a comment, `os.system` runs the command with `/bin/sh`.  Even if this is a link to `/bin/bash`, when Bash is run as `/bin/sh`, it switches to a POSIX-conforming mode where Bash-specific syntax (like the command you're running) doesn't work.

One solution is to use:

```
os.system("/bin/bash -c 'ls > >(tee -a a)'")
```

This is pretty gross -- it uses the shell `/bin/sh` to run a new shell `/bin/bash` to run the desired command.  If you really wanted to do this, using the functions in package `subprocess` to run Bash directly would be cleaner.

In this case, though, I think there's a simpler solution.  The "pipe" syntax:

```
os.system("ls | tee -a a")
```

is `/bin/sh`-compatible, and I think it achieves the same thing you are trying to do here.

As noted in another comment, it isn't that hard to do this in pure Python, either:

```
# Python 3
with open("a", "a") as o:
    for f in os.listdir("."):
        print(f)
        print(f, file=o)

# Python 2
with open("a", "a") as o:
    for f in os.listdir("."):
        print f
        print >>o, f
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! But for me my bash command have use `'` and `"`, so can't just add a `'` pair to surround the command. Is there a way to make my command work?

Answer (score 1):

os.system will be replaced by [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). Here is a solution with subprocess.Popen

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen("ls", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdoutdata, _ = process.communicate()
print stdoutdata
with open ("a", "a") as fle:
    fle.write(stdoutdata)
```